# How to calculate degree of freedom for pooled variance?

Tags: variance, pooling

**05/08/2017 update - more on background:** Each lab contributes multiple test results for that same sample, all collected by the same operator on a single instrument. Then for each lab, I calculate the sample variance of the multiple test results (just the square of the standard deviation of all the data, not concerned about sampling distribution of the mean), and I use this sample variance to represent the variability of the data submitted by this lab.

**Background:** I'm estimating variability of test results submitted by different labs on the same sample. For each lab I can obtain a variance estimate, so for the network that consists of all those labs, I have the pooled variance. Then I need to construct confidence intervals from the pooled variance, and this is why I need to have the degree of freedom.

**Question:** For pooled variance, I've seen some say the degree of freedom is just the denominator of the pooled variance, and others say we need to use Welch–Satterthwaite equation to calculate dof for the pooled variance. Which is correct?

Comment: Welch approximation is for testing mean differences when variances are known/assumed to be different.  The variances are estimated separately and not pooled.  The normality assumption is made and the degrees of freedom is chosen to get the best approximate t statistic.

Comment: This question is a bit like asking "which medicine is better for me: aspirin or ibuprofen."  No competent physician would give you an unqualified answer.  In this case, the reason why variations of any test exist is to handle variations in the behavior of the data, differences in your assumptions about the data, and different decision-making objectives.  Since you haven't stipulated any of these things, there can be no definite answer: sometimes one is a better choice and sometimes another.

Comment: @whuber I updated my question with more background, hopefully this can help you provide an answer.

Comment: That helps a lot.  However, could you be more specific about what this "variance estimate" is attempting to estimate?  In this context it could be many different things, including an intra-lab variance and a sampling variance for a mean.